# Как динамически добавить в модель данные

Tags: javascript, ember.js

в action findChilds, сделать запрос, в моем случае данные храняться в firebase и полученные данные добавить к уже выбранным. Данные мне приходят, а что дальше делать не могу понять... Как их добавить к модели, чтобы отобразить в шаблоне?

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return this.store.query('category', {
      orderBy: 'parent',
      equalTo: 'null'
    });
  },

  actions: {

    deleteCategory(category) {
      let confirmation = confirm('Are you sure?');

      if (confirmation) {
        category.destroyRecord();
      }
    },

    findChilds(id) {
      // вот здесь к примеру сделать запрос
      var childs = this.store.query('category', {
      orderBy: 'parent',
      equalTo: id
     });
    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
findChilds(id) {
  this.store.query('category', {
    orderBy: 'parent',
    equalTo: id
 }).then((records) => {
   this.get('controller.model').pushObjects(records);
 });
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже понял)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.